# Using a box shadow on a div but I can still tab through the underlying elements

Tags: html, css

I have created a dialog box that appears when you click on an element on the page. The div box then appears with a huge box shadow to prevent the user from accessing the underlying (orginal) elements on the page. Except its doesnt, the user can still tab through the items under the .overlayme div

I have scaled my code down and writen this little example to demonstrate what i mean.
If you click on the first button and tab through the rest, when actually what i am trying to achieve is preveent the user from clicking on the first button and only being able to tab on the "eventually you", "will get here" buttons.

My mark up is here

```
<html><head></head><body><input type="button" value="click me first" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="now tab to me" />   
<div class="overlayme">
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>
<input type="button" value="eventually you" />
&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="will get here" /></div></body></html>​​​​
```

and my css is here

```
.overlayme input{ background-color:lightgrey; }
.overlayme {
max-width: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
position: relative;
background: white;}
input{
background-color:white;}
```

So basically in short .. The problem is that i can still access the underlying elements and i want them to be disabled and only be able to access the items on the .overlayme div.

Is it possible to disable this lower level with css or does this have to be a js thing?
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8BPMk/1/

Comment: what's your problem? tell as simple.

Comment: The problem is that i can still access the underlying elements and i want them to be disabled and only be able to access the items on the .overlayme div... thanks (i have re-editted my original to make it clearer.. thanks)

Comment: @AttikAttak You overlay doesn't actually mask it as it is a box-shadow and won't affect users ability to interact with it.

Comment: check latest fiddle please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gQEUx/

you need to add fixer div with absolute positioning and 100% width and heigth

```
.fixer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and

```
<div class="fixer">
  <div class="overlayme">
    <br/>&nbsp;<br/>
    <input type="button" value="eventually you" />
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="will get here" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gQEUx/1/, thanks to **@AbstractChaos**

```
$('.fixer').hide();

$('#example').click(function() {
  $('.fixer').toggle('slow');
  if($('.fixer').is(':visible')) {
    $('input').attr('tabIndex','-1');    
  }
  else {
      $('input').attr('tabIndex','1');
  }
});
```

so from this - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#tabbing-navigation

and this - http://nemisj.com/focusable/

and this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

elements that can be tabindexed are:

msdn:

```
The following elements can have focus and are tab stops by default: a, BODY, button, frame, iframe, img, input, isIndex, object, select, textArea.

The following elements can have focus by default but are not tab stops. These elements can be set as tab stops by setting the tabIndex property to a positive integer. applet, div, frameSet, span, table, td.
```

w3c:

```
The following elements support the tabindex attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.
```

and i haven't read third article, think that would be enough already

**EDIT: should do the job - http://jsfiddle.net/gQEUx/3/**

```
$('.fixer').hide();

$('#example').click(function() {
    $('.fixer').toggle('slow');
    if($('.fixer').is(':visible')) {
      $('a, AREA, BODY, button, frame, iframe, img, input, isIndex, object, select, textArea, applet, div, frameSet, span, table, td')
      .attr('tabIndex','-1');    
    }
    else {
      $('a, AREA, BODY, button, frame, iframe, img, input, isIndex, object, select, textArea, applet, div, frameSet, span, table, td')
      .attr('tabIndex','1');
    }

});
```

Comment: this is a good step but also need to disable the tab back from the dialog buttons. Use Javascript to set `tabIndex = -1` on buttons that shouldnt be available.

Comment: ah, one moment, missed that

Comment: try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQEUx/1/), wont allow you to tab to the other buttons

Comment: Hi there. The example i created a simplified version of something a lot more complete in the original i need the tabindex :( when the overlayme div is not there. Though i suppose i could make some jquery to remove all tabindexes if the div is displayed

Comment: I have just got round to implementing it it and everything works fine, except my tab key can still tab on other elements on the first layer like hyperlinks etc is there some way to disable this? thanks for any of your ideas

Comment: when you click button in popup, it got selected and then you can navigate to links with ctrl-tab, i think better to add tabindex=-1 to each element that can be tabindexed, i will update answer